# Laravel interface not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I have the following two classes:

My interface inside app/Contracts:

```
namespace App\Contracts;

use App\Models\Lead;

interface CRMServiceContract
{
    public function generateLead(Lead $lead);
}
```

My service class inside app/Services/CRM:

```
namespace App\Services\CRM;

use App\Contracts\CRMServiceContract;
use App\Services\CRM\CRMService;
use App\Models\Lead;

class ELeadService extends CRMService implements CRMServiceContract
{
    public function generateLead(Lead $lead)
    {

    }
}
```

Inside my composer.json

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
```

My service class is found correctly. But I'm receiving an error that

`Interface "App\Contracts\CRMServiceContract" not found`

I've checked the spellings, ran artisan clear cache, and composer dump-autoload. Also, the IDE correctly recognizes the interface class, but the app is failing.

Comment: Sometimes, changes made to the application's code may not be reflected immediately due to the application's cache. Therefore, clearing the cache can help resolve this issue. To clear the cache, run the following command in your terminal: 
php artisan cache:clear

If clearing the cache does not resolve the issue, you can try running the following command to optimize the application's class autoloader:
composer dump-autoload -o

If neither of these solutions works, you may want to check your application's configuration to ensure that the correct paths and namespaces are being used.

Comment: @MonayemIslam I did both and still no luck. I even moved the interface to a different folder and changed the namespace, still has the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

My interface file was missing the `.php` extension. ‍♂️